# How do i implement drag delta on grid when grid column*row (4*5) staying on canvas in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I have created the usercontrol as like below.Please help me.
Please see the below code my xaml code :

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DeepPink" Width="200" Height="150" x:Name="TempMaxEntityBorder">

    <Canvas  x:Name="TempMaxEntityCanvas" Background="LightPink" Focusable="True" AllowDrop="True"  Tag="MatrixEntityCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

        <Grid x:Name="GridLayout" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Entity" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200"></TextBlock>
            <Line Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Stroke="DeepPink" StrokeThickness="2" X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Grid  x:Name="ChildGridLayout" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DeepPink" ></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="a"   Padding="22,5"/>
                <Rectangle  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="a"   Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="a"   Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="a"   Padding="22,0"/>

                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DeepPink"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="b"   Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="b"   Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="b"   Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="b"   Padding="22,0"/>

                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DeepPink"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="c" Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="c" Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="c" Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Text="c" Padding="22,0"/>

                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DeepPink"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="d" Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="d" Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Text="d" Padding="22,0"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Text="d" Padding="22,0"/>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

[image]

I write my thumb code in c# file and this work good.
But when i using dragDelta on canvas through thumb,this canvas resize using thumb but grid does not resize.Grid staying in same position. [image]

Thanks in advance. So how to bind grid with this parent canvas.

Comment: To bind to the actual size of the canvas:  `<Grid x:Name="GridLayout" Height="{Binding ElementName=TempMaxEntityCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
                      Width="{Binding ElementName=TempMaxEntityCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}">`

Answer (score 0):

You are choosing a wrong container (Canvas) for layout. Canvas places its children using *absolute positioning*, which means the position of each children is defined as `[offsetX, offSetY]` to the canvas. When the canvas resizes, the children stay where they were. The `VerticalAlignment/HorizontalAlignment` property does not work if the container is a Canvas.

```
<Grid x:Name="GridLayout" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Further reading on [WPF Canvas layout](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-layout-canvas/).

You can workaround this by binding the Width/Height of `GridLayout` to the actual width/height of the Canvas. But a better solution to this is choosing `Grid` as the container.

I have deleted the Canvas, also replaced some column/row definitions from `Auto` to `*` (You can also test the difference between the two).

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DeepPink" x:Name="TempMaxEntityBorder" Margin="159,85,137.667,55.667">
    <Grid x:Name="GridLayout" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Entity" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200"></TextBlock>
        <Line Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Stroke="DeepPink" StrokeThickness="2" X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Grid  x:Name="ChildGridLayout" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DeepPink" ></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="a"   Padding="22,5"/>
            <Rectangle  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="a"   Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="a"   Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="a"   Padding="22,0"/>

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DeepPink"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="b"   Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="b"   Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="b"   Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="b"   Padding="22,0"/>

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DeepPink"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="c" Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="c" Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="c" Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Text="c" Padding="22,0"/>

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DeepPink"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="d" Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="d" Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Text="d" Padding="22,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="DeepPink" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Text="d" Padding="22,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I know this difference between `auto` & `*`. But may be you don't understand my problem.My problem is that when i keep **leftMouseButtonDown** on thumb  and resize this canvas,this can i do but  this grid can't binding with canvas for this reason grid can't resize and staying on same position and canvas resize.So how to bind grid with this parent canvas.

Comment: The solution is getting rid of canvas (and using grid). The grid can resizes with the canvas if you use data binding, but unless you choose canvas for some particular reason, I don't think it is the right choice.